# How to convert an XML FIle into a SimpleXMLElement() Array?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

I have an XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<deadlines>
    <deadline>
        <date>2010-07-01</date>
        <text>Residency Application for Fall Due</text>
    </deadline>
    <deadline>
        <date>2010-06-01</date>
        <text>Residency Application for Summer Due</text>
    </deadline>
    <deadline>
        <date>2010-07-20</date>
        <text>Summer Bill Due</text>
    </deadline>
</deadlines>
```

When I load the file into a PHP script using simplexml_load_file(), I get the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [deadline] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [date] => 2010-07-01
                    [text] => Residency Application for Fall Due
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [date] => 2010-06-01
                    [text] => Residency Application for Summer Due
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [date] => 2010-07-20
                    [text] => Summer Bill Due
                )

        )

)
```

In order for my script to handle the XML file as an array, I need to parse the file and get it into this format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [date] => 2010-07-01
            [text] => Residency Application for Fall Due
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [date] => 2010-06-01
            [text] => Residency Application for Summer Due
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [date] => 2010-07-20
            [text] => Summer Bill Due
        )

)
```

IS there a PHP function to convert the XML file? Thanks

Comment: Seems you could just use `$xml->deadline` as the array.

Comment: Hmm, tried that earlier on and it did not do the job...I'll try again -- maybe I had a syntax issue or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$deadlines = array();
$sxe = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
foreach($sxe->deadline as $deadline) {
    $deadlines[] = $deadline;
}
print_r($deadlines);
```

or

```
$sxe = (array) new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
print_r( $sxe['deadline'] );
```

---

**EDIT** sorry, I assumed you were familiar enough with SimpleXml to know that the [constructor of SimpleXmlElement assumes you are passing the XML as a string](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php). Either change the line to read

```
$sxe = new SimpleXmlElement($filename, NULL, TRUE);
```

or replace it with

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way of doing it.

```
<?php
$data = (array)simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$data = array_pop($data);
print_r($data);
?>
```